# For/in probem. What is the difference between object.variable and object[variable]?

Tags: for-loop, object

Why can we use a code like this:

```
     let student = {name:"John", surname:"Doe", index:386754}; 
     let text = "";
     let x;
     for (x in student) {
     text += student[x] + " ";   }
```

And it would preview: John Doe 386754.

But when I formulated it like this:

```
     let student = {name:"John", surname:"Doe", index:386754}; 
     let text = "";
     let x;
     for (x in student) {
     text += student.x + " ";   }
```

, it returnes: undefined undefined undefined.

I suppose it's a pretty basic thing, but I had to ask because I can't find an appropriate answer.
Thank you ahead!

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the data structures. You create a hash table using the variable `student`. So you can call inner variables (key-value pairs) by using brackets as you did `student[name]`. The second one `student.name` means you are calling a method of a class, which you don't have.

I recommend you to check what data structures exist, and how to use them.

Answer (score 0):

The usage of `object.something` vs `object[something]` varies in different languages, and JavaScript is particularly loose in this aspect. The big difference here is that in `object[something]`, `something` must reference a string corresponding to a key in `object`. So if you had `something = 'myKey'`, and `myKey` was the name of a key in `something` (so `object = {'myKey': 'value', ...}`), you would get `value`. If you use `object.something`, you are asking JavaScript to look for a key in `object` with the name something. Even if you write `something = 'myKey'`, using a dot means that you are looking within the scope of the object, making variables in your program effectively invisible.

So when you write `student.x`, you get undefined because there is no key `'x': 'value'` in `student` for your program to find. Defining `x` as a key in your for loop does not change this. On the other hand, writing `student[x]` means that your program is finding the value `x` is referencing and plugging it in. When `x` is `'name'`, the program is actually looking for `student['name']`.

Hope that clarifies your issue. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for such an extensive but concrete answer. Now it's much clearer to me.